# Java Vuser on LoadRunner 11.52 not working

Tags: java, loadrunner, replay

Recently I have started testing of some application which are Java based. Now the problem is even if I put a simple statement lik;

```
lr.output_message("Hello");
```

nothihng is coming up. I havw already set the classpath and jdk path, no error is coming while compilation but during run time no display is coming up.

Sample Script

```
import lrapi.lr;
import lrapi.web;


public class Actions
{

    public int init() throws Throwable 
    {
        return 0;
    }//end of init


    public int action() throws Throwable 
    {
        lr.start_transaction("trans1");
        System.out.println("Lin 1");
        lr.output_message("Error");
        lr.message("Pulkit");
        lr.end_transaction("trans1",lr.AUTO);
        return 0;
    }//end of action


    public int end() throws Throwable {


        return 0;
    }//end of end
}
```

......................

Actually by doing some R&D the same code is working on 9.52 but not on 11.52 so is it a bug?? can anyone suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

I have another hypothesis.   Since you have switched versions the environment is not yet set correctly for 11.52, but it is for 9.52.   This could be due to many things, such as installing a 64 bit edition of Java on your 11.52 box and a 32 bit edition on your 9.52 box and then expecting the same results.    Perhaps even installing an unsupported version of Java under 11.52, but a supported version under 9.52.    Start scoping the differences.  Document them well for you will have to take the same setup to your 11.52 load generators for reproduction there.